# Timezone information (zoneinfo) is out-of-date on Dokku. How to update?

Tags: dokku

Recently, the Brazilian government abolished the daylight saving time where the timezone offset went from -3 to -2.

My Dokku container still contains the old information, causing my Ruby on Rails application that reads directly from the OS zoneinfo to display times in DST when it shouldn't.

I can check that my host machine has up-to-date timezone information because when I run `TZ=":America/Sao_Paulo" date` it outputs `Fri Nov 8 12:10:xx -03 2019`. Running the same command inside my Dokku container outputs `Fri Nov 8 13:10:xx -02 2019`.

How can I update my Dokku time zone information and make it persistent between deployments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve it, I did the following steps:

1. run `docker system prune -a`
2. run `dokku ps:rebuild [app-name]`

The first command cleared the Docker image cache for `gliderlabs/herokuish:latest` which contained the Heroku stack with the out-of-date timezone information. The second command rebuilt the app from source downloading the newer herokuish image.